# linux - how to compare 2 filesystem blocks

Tags: linux, postgresql, filesystems, compare

Is there a way to compare (binary or checksum etc) file blocks between 2 different linux servers. The files on both the servers are residing in SAN. Reason - replication is setup on postgres database, i want to check if the blocks for a table in both the primary and mirror will they exactly the same or different for tables?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that they should be the same?

Comment: i think they should be same since the replication is block level replication but wanted a way to confirm.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I wasn't sure if Postgres did block level replication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `dd` to read the block of the file you care about, and then pipe it to `md5sum` to get a checksum that I can compare to the other machine, like:

```
$ dd if=/path/to/postgresql/data bs=4096 skip=<block number minus one> count=1 | md5sum
5561f64d760047a7a56e99a71a66c890
```

(You should substitute your own block size in the `bs=` parameter if 4KB isn't right for PostgreSQL.)